# Is it possible to use NuxtLink to a Vue "component" in the components directory vs. a "page" route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to create a form that I want to use modularly by linking to it from multiple page templates.  Using just the straight vue-cli I would simply create a route to the file that has the form defined that I store in the "components" directory and then wrap a button linking to the form in a `<router-link to="componentFormName"><btn></btn></router-link>`.  I'm having some difficulty determining how to do the equivalent in Nuxt.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.  It seems the `<NuxtLink></NuxtLink>` only works with Vue files in the "Pages" directory.

Comment: Gotcha, I did that -- thanks again for your help and thoughts with this:-). Out of curiosity, what are you hoping to achieve by going through this formality?

Comment: That's cool;-) Got another question for you... Is there a way to place a vue flash message (vue-flash-message - npm) in a particular place.  It seems like the props you put in for position "left top, left bottom," etc.  ```<FlashMessage :position="'right top'"></FlashMessage>``` overrides placing them inside vuetify elements.

Comment: Not familiar with this specific package. So I could not answer in a comment in a few lines. Feel free to create a new question and put all the relevant stuff there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use dynamic components here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components

With something like this

```html
<component :is="currentTabComponent"></component>
```

With `currentTabComponent` being one of the component to mount. You can mount a component depending of the current route with a relation between the URL and the component name too.

---

Also, Vue does not have any knowledge of "route", and everything is a component. Nothing really changes with a `page` because it is also a component at the end of the day. Or you could write one inside of it.

Maybe an example of your use-case would be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks Kissu.  This appears to be a Vue answer, I need a Nuxt solution to this problem.  Conceptually what I want is a generic form component that I can link to from multiple pages.  With the vue-cli implementation I would have multiple "view(s)" / page templates that reference a single reusable form component that I route to.  For instance the form could have 4 attributes - address, phone number, first name, last name.  Say I had two pages/views  "/user/create" /user/update" they both would share the same form although each may have unique attributes of their own.

Comment: The linked code is also compatible with Nuxt. There is no big difference between Vue and Nuxt, it's only conventions and SSR at the end. If you want to have 2 different pages `/user/create` and `/user/update`, you can totally import the component in it and make it dynamic depending of the path!

Comment: I've done that and it works, was just curious if I could have it as a component b/c technically that is what it is.  Thanks again.

Comment: A page or a component, it's basically the same. A page will allow for less configuration, baked in easier transitions, `asyncData` hooks and alike. You could eventually expand your own router and tell it to load the component but you will also loose the benefit of `layouts`. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views So, you cannot directly link a path to a component but at the end, a page can be a component. Or you could load it without even relying directly on the router. A lot of different approaches, for the same result at the end.